# Create a function to return a movie name

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

For learning purposes as a newbie in SQL, I created a function successfully:

```
create function Movie_Search 
    (@FilmName as nvarchar(255))
returns nvarchar(255)
as
begin
    declare @Film nvarchar(255)

    select @Film = (select filmname 
                    from [dbo].[tblFilm]
                    where FilmName like '%'+@FilmName+'%')

    return @Film
end
```

The idea is to search a film's name from this function, but the `select [Movie_Search]('star')` throws this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 28
> Incorrect syntax near 'star'.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please edit your question and include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your issue. This looks like SqlServer and should be a table-valued function - how to you handle multiple matches?

Comment: please show how you make use of the function

Comment: A function when called must always be preprended by the schema it's in - and if you have a `NVARCHAR` parameter, use a `N` prefix for the string literal - so please try: `SELECT dbo.movie_search(N'star');`

Comment: @jarlh yes I am using SQL server

Comment: @GordonLinoff it is tagged to sql db

Comment: It is listed in my question @Squirrel

Comment: I would really suggest switching this from a multi-line scalar function to an inline table-value function; they are *far* more performant. Note the above will also fail if you find more than one film, which with a `WHERE` clause like that is easily within the realm of expectation. Another reason to switch to a iTVF, as you aren't limited to a scalar value.

Comment: I tried with "SELECT dbo.movie_search(N'star');" did not make any change. See the error below -->Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 28
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. @marc_s

Comment: @Beni check the above comment from me; I just warned you about this,.

Comment: I will give it a try thanks @Larnu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, as I mention in the comments, this function will cause an error if more than one film is found, due to the method you are using to assign the value of `@Film`. If multiple films are found then you are going to get an error telling you the subquery returned multiple rows.

Instead you should be using an inline table-value function here, which along with handing multiple rows, is more performant than a multi-line scalar function.

This would look something like this:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Movie_Search (@FilmName nvarchar(255))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
    SELECT FilmName
    FROM dbo.tblFilm
    WHERE FilmName LIKE N'%' + @FilmName + N'%';
```

And then you would call the function like below:

```sql
SELECT FilmName
FROM dbo.Movie_Search(N'Star') MS;
```

Comment: @Beni . . . This totally changes what you are doing.  A table-valued function is quite different from a scalar function.  No doubt, it might work for your needs, but it doesn't really seem like an answer to the question you asked.

Comment: I completely disagree, @GordonLinoff . The OP clearly demonstrates, from the comments, they are expecting multiple values, which a scalar function can't do. Plus the fact that a multi-line scalar function tend to be less performant as well, mean that moving to a iTVF is a far better solution.

Comment: *If* however, the OP does want to learn how to write a scalar function, we can certainly show them, however, it would not be fit for purpose for the scenario they are trying to fulfil here (so would be better in a different question in my opinion). There's little point using a hammer to put in a screw, when you have a perfectly suitable screwdriver in your toolbox; especially for someone new to the language. Teach them correctly to start with.